# Join two columns of the same table ignoring the null value. MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join two columns of the same table but, if there are null values (in my case they are in the second column), I want to take anyway the row that interests me and, rather than putting the null value, I would put `''`. The columns that I want to join are `Surname` and `Name`. In other words, I tried to use :

```
SELECT CONCAT(CSurname, ' ', CName)
FROM Client;
```

In this way if I have a valid value for surname and a null value for name I obtain null. I use MySql, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the problem with a leading space, then the easiest way is probably `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', CSurname, CName)
FROM Client;
```

Unlike most other functions, `CONCAT_WS()` ignores `NULL` values (except for the separator), greatly simplifying this logic -- particularly when you are working with more than two columns.

Without it, the equivalent logic could be expressed as:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(CSurname, ' '), ''), COALESCE(CName, ''))
```

Comment: If I haven't a surname value, I obtain a space and a name, that are positioned at the head of the table. What can I do for ignore this space and order alphabetically my information?

Comment: @salvo9415 . . . Is the missing value `NULL` or an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [ifnull](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function

```
SELECT CONCAT(CSurname, ' ', IFNULL(CName,'')) FROM Client;
```

I don't have a local mysql installation to try it out but the IFNULL function should achieve what you need.